# Facebook Apps that actually redirect to an external website

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have seen some Facebook apps that instead of being normal apps with the Canvas iframe, instead redirect the user to the external website instead e.g.

http://www.facebook.com/foursquare

See how the go to app link goes to the website instead, and if you see a post in the timeline or news feed the link that says `via Foursquare` that shows a popup when you hover it also links directly to the website.

Example of this is also on the Neowin app page:

[image]

My question is how do you create this?

As I have created a Facebook page for a product I am building that will be allowing users to post to their timeline etc but won't actually be an app as the site itself is the app rather than being an iframe viewed on Facebook.

It can't be any redirect scripts as the url shown in the browser status bar for the links is the actual website so the links themselves have been modified rather than redirecting the user when they access the canvas page...

Comment: @webarto: please be _civil_... I dislike FB as much as the next curmudgeon, but as FB questions go this one is far better than usual.

Comment: @webarto I fail to see how this is a stupid question... I find the fact that you spelt 'ever' incorrectly far more stupid! In any case, it's a question without an answer... hopefully someone with knowledge will answer instead of just trolls like you! And dislike Facebook? What the heck are you doing on a Facebook QnA site then???

Comment: @Cameron please note that what you think is a facebook Q&A is actually a programming Q&A called stackoverflow. facebook.stack is just SO with only [facebook] tagged questions.

Comment: My question is programming related though. As it's application development on Facebook.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/

Comment: That blog post explains my point. It's SO for Facebook developers as a replacement for their old forum.

Comment: @Cameron No you failed to read. It's not SO for Facebook. It's SO. The question you post are on SO.

Comment: In the time people have complained the question could of actually being answered... why do people feel the need to troll...

Comment: My comments are in no way meant to troll. I just wanted to point out that you point is invalid. "What the heck are you doing on a Facebook QnA site then???" I do agree with your first point though about webarto.

Comment: Well in any case can people move on to helping please...

Comment: @Cameron: Reverse engineer the application you name as an example (which might be considered as: do your homework [see the FAQ]) - otherwise you ask just others to reverse-engineer this for you which is not helpful.

Comment: Reverse engineer someone else's Facebook app... what is going on here!

Comment: @Cameron: You can start with the client side code and markup, like the HTML and the JS you receive.

Comment: Why is this so difficult for people to answer...

Comment: Upvote, because this is a Facebook Developer question.

Answer (score 4):

Well I see this as a valid question for facebook.stackoverflow.

Aside from your page, you'll need to create an app in the [Facebook Apps Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). In the app settings, just check website and input your URL. Leave the canvas page "App on Facebook" unchecked.

Going to the application, or clicking the link at the bottom of a post will automatically open the website, not the canvas.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. I've been searching for hours. I can't understand why the original question was closed as unconstructive.

To update your answer for 2014. After creating you app, you will need to:
1. go to you app page
2. go to **settings** 
3. click **Add Platform** button
4. Select website option
5. Enter URL of your website and save